# Limit of inverse function

Tags: limits

I need some help with the following question.
Let $f$ be a real-valued one-to-one function with domain $(a-1, a+1)$.
Let $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$. Prove or disprove: $\lim_{y \to L} f^{-1}(y)=a$.

Comment: Common sense???

Comment: @Awesome: What do you mean??

Comment: if $f(a)=L$ then $f^{-1}(L)=a$ Am I missing something?

Comment: @Awesome Yes, but this is about a limit. What about http://i.imgur.com/CPMJs0b.png

Comment: I don't see how that makes a difference @user2345215. Wont that limit be f(a).

Comment: @Awesome You’re assuming continuity.

Comment: @k.stm But both sided limits are equal and hence it makes no difference

Comment: @Awesome Which limits are equal, what makes no difference and how does that follow?

Comment: @k.stm The limit $exists$

Comment: @Awesome Why and how does this help?

Comment: @Awesome Then prove it. Even though I believe I showed you a counterexample.

Comment: I have no intent of explaining obvious things which I see.

Comment: @user2345215 Anyways... limit exists and function is continuous as it is one-one

Comment: ????????????????? - this is my last post in this discussion

Comment: @Awesome Yeah, right. Either you have something to contribute or not. If you say you don’t have, then don’t say anything at all. It’s noise.

Comment: @user2345215 Apparently not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I = (-1..1)$. We’ll construct a one-to-one function $f \colon I → I$ such that $\lim_{x → 0} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x → -1} f(x) = 0 = \lim_{x → 1} f(x)$.

This is how $f$ looks like:
$$f \colon I → I, \quad f(x) =
\begin{cases}
f_l(x) \quad &\text{for $x ∈ (-1..-1/2)$} \\
f_c(x) \quad &\text{for $x ∈ [-1/2..1/2]$} \\
f_r(x) \quad &\text{for $x ∈ (1/2..1)$}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Now we need to define $f_l$, $f_c$ and $f_r$ appropriately.

For $x ∈ [-1..1]$, let’s look at balls $B_n(x) = \{y ∈ I; |x-y| < 1/n$} and their successive differences $C_n(x) = B_{n}(x) \setminus B_{n+1}(x)$. These are rings! So we’re splitting balls around $x$ into rings which get tinier and tinier the closer they become to $x$.

We will now create bijections:
\begin{align*}
l_n &\colon C_{n+1}(-1) → C_{3n - 1}(0)\\
c_n &\colon C_{n}(0) → C_{3n}(0), \\
r_n &\colon C_{n+1}(1) → C_{3n + 1}(0)
\end{align*}
(With $l_n$ and $r_n$ the codomain is $C_{n+1}(\pm 1)$ instead of $C_n(\pm 1)$ because we only need to cover $B_2(\pm 1)$ in the end.)
These will yield exactly the one-to-one functions we need
\begin{align*}
f_l &= \bigsqcup_{n ∈ ℕ} l_n \colon B_2(-1) → I\\
f_c &= \bigsqcup_{n ∈ ℕ} c_n \colon B_1(0) → I \\
f_r &= \bigsqcup_{n ∈ ℕ} r_n \colon B_2(1) → I \\
\end{align*}
This works since $B_k (x) = \bigsqcup_{n = k}^{∞} C_n(x)$. Well, actually, there are yet few technicalities: One should set $C_∞(x) = \{x\}$ for $x ∈ I$ as well as $f_c (0) = 0$ and $f_c (1/2) = 1/2$ and $f_c (-1/2) = 1/2$.

So what are $l_n$, $c_n$ and $r_n$? Just let them be (affine) linear.

Now $f$ is one-to-one and obviously $\lim_{x → 0} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x → -1} f(x) = 0 = \lim_{x → 1} f(x)$. But you can’t say anything about $\lim_{y → 0} f^{-1}(y)$, can you?

Comment: I hate how it's so obvious, yet one does have to do so much work to construct that. :(